# Set a global alias for a table and a column?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I'm working with a huge Firebird database where tables have completely unreadable names like `WTF$RANDOM_ABBREVIATION_6792` or `RPG$RANDOM_ABBREVIATION_5462` where columns have names like "`rid9312`", "`1NUM5`", "`2NUM4`", "`RNAME8`".

I need to set them global aliases to be able to use them as a full-length table names like `Document` and column names like

`Document.CreationDate` instead of `xecblob.DDATE4`
or

`TempDoc.MovingOrderID` instead of `TMP$LINKED_DOC_6101.DID6101`

Altering the database, or a table, or a column might be a big problem because the records might be counted by millions and tens of millions, and more over that, a major part of the Delphi-written front-end for the database is bound to the table names and column names.

Is there a way to do that somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing there is to a "global alias" is to create [views](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-ddl-view.html). For example:

```sql
create view document
as
select 
  DDATE4 as creationdate
  -- , other columns...
from xecblob;
```

or

```sql
create view document (creationdate /*, other column aliases... */)
as
select 
  DDATE4
  -- , other columns...
from xecblob;
```

(personally, I find the first variant more readable)

This does require altering the database, but there is no real cost associated with that (it doesn't matter if the table contains no, one, thousands or millions of records).